# MIT Scheme List Sorted in Ascending order

Tags: list, sorting, scheme, procedure

I'm taking a practice exam for a course in programming that deals with MIT Scheme. One of the questions asks:

"Complete the procedure (in-order ls) to return the list ls, except stop just before the first value that is not *strictly greater* than the previous value in ls. In other words, in-order should return the portion of ls *starting from the beginning* that is *sorted in strictly increasing order*. Assume that ls contains only non-negative integers."

The question then shows several examples:

```
(in-order '(1 2 3 4)) ; should return (1 2 3 4)
(in-order '(1 2 3 3 4 5)) ; should return (1 2 3)
(in-order '(3 2)) ; should return (3)
(in-order '(3)) ; should return (3)
```

This is my attempt at a solution:

```
(define (in-order ls)
  (cond ((null? ls) ls)
        ((< (car ls) (cadr ls)) 
         (cons (car ls) (cons (in-order (cdr ls)) ())))
        ((>= (car ls) (cadr ls)) (car ls))
        (else "Nothing")))
```

It comes close to working with the 2nd and 3rd example, but outright fails with the 1st and 4th example. I know that it keeps trying to pass a null as part of the argument, but I'm unsure of how to work around this. Other than that, is there anything else that I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you there:

```
(define (in-order ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '()
      (let looking ((result (list (car ls))) (ls (cdr ls)))
        (if (or (null? ls) (not (< (car result) (car ls))))
            (reverse result)
            (looking (cons (car ls) result)
                     (cdr ls))))))
```

The tail recursive `looking` always has the last value as the result's `car`.  So the comparison for stopping becomes `(not (< (car result) (car ls)))`

In your code the `(cons (in-order ...) ())` is almost surely wrong.  The predicate `(< (car ls) (cadr ls))` will fail on anything like `'(3)` - you need something like `(null? (cdr ls))` to avoid that.

In a non-tail recursive algorithm, similar to yours, it would be:

```
(define (in-order ls)
  (cond ((or (null? ls) (null? (cdr ls))) ls)     ; nothing left
        ((< (car ls) (cadr ls))                   ; extend and continue
         (cons (car ls) (in-order (cdr ls))))
        (else (list (car ls)))))                  ; last one
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was under the impression that I shouldn't be concatenating a null onto my in-order procedure called recursively. I put that there more so that I could troubleshoot the (1 2 . 3) error I kept getting. I also knew that there was something else that the else should be used for, which is why I was considering rewriting it with if's. I appreciate the rewritten alternative, as well as the corrected version.